# Caching in Webview is not working in Android

Tags: android, caching, webview, browser-cache, offline-caching

When I open webview, it runs great when there is a network connection, but I have enabled caching in it, and without a network connection, it shows an error and loaded cached web page is not showing.

I have enabled caching and also set cache mode, but it's not working.

My **webview** code is below:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, container, false);
        WebView heroespage = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webSettings = heroespage.getSettings();
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        heroespage.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientSubClass());
        heroespage.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E0FyHR_lCQce0NPnQL8z1XJp78XW6eLdO8CkeibTdgg/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq&gid=2");
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to cache documents from docs.google.com like this.

The server can send a `cache-control` header as response to any request to set rules for the client about caching.
As these documents from docs.google.com are never static, the response contains the instruction to don't cache your document.

```
cache-control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

The Android WebView accept these rules and don't cache your site.

Comment: But can you say me then how can I saw something like sheet in web view..... I want to display time table and something like that in web view.. Is there anything like spreadsheet???

Comment: In my case caching didn't work because of unsecure HTTPS.